# Convert base64 string to array of decimal binaries in PHP

Tags: php, rest, api

I have some base64 encoded files which I want to convert into arrays of decimal binaries(It's the only format accepted by the API I want to send them to)

So I would have this:
    VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIDEzIGxhenkgZG9ncy4=

and want to convert it to:
    [84,104,101,32,113,117,105,99,107,32,98,114,111,119,110,32,102,111,120,32,106,117,109,112,115,32,111,118,101,114,32,49,51,32,108,97,122,121,32,100,111,103,115,46]

Is there a native function in PHP to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site for coding. To receive better answers, please show code attempts. In the case of the above, maybe try searching on the site first and attempting to use what you've found.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JJFord3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the ASCII character codes of the decoded base64 string. First, we decode the base64 string, convert it to an array, and iterate over each element applying [ord](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php).

```
$base64String = 'VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIDEzIGxhenkgZG9ncy4';
$result = array_map(function ($char) {
    return ord($char);
}, str_split(base64_decode($base64String)));
```

See: [base64_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php), [ord](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)